# Can we make a non-blocking server with blocking sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, select

I have to make a simple IRC client/server programs for my IT school. The subject asks us to use `select(2)` for socket polling but forbids us to use `O_NONBLOCK` sockets.

> - Your server will accept multiple simultaneous connections.
>     **Attention, the use of `fork` is prohibited. So you should imperatively use `select`**
> - Your server must not be blocking.
>     **This has nothing to do with non-blocking sockets, which are prohibited (so do not use `fcntl(s, O_NONBLOCK)`)**

I’m wondering if it is even possible to design a non-blocking server (which does not fork) with blocking sockets even using `select(2)`.

Here is a simple example: let say we have a simple text protocol with one command per line. Each client has a buffer. When `select(2)` tells us a client is ready for `read(2)`, we read until we found a `\n` in the client buffer, therefor we process the command. With non-blocking sockets, we would read until `EAGAIN`.

Let imagine now that we are using blocking sockets and a malicious client sends text with no line-break. `select(2)` tells us data is available, we then `read(2)` on the client. But we will never read the expected `\n`. Instead of returning `EAGAIN`, the syscall will block indefinitely. This is a denial of service attack.

Is it really possible to design a non-blocking server with blocking-sockets and `select(2)` (no `fork(2)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you read once from the socket that `select` tells you is ready. If the `read` contains the `\n`, then process that line. Otherwise, store any data that was received, and immediately go back to the `select`.

This means of course, that for every open socket, you must maintain state information, and a buffer of data read so far. This allows the code to process each `read` independently, without the need to finish a full line before going back to the `select`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense; then you have to do only one `read` call, right?

Comment: When `select()` exits, one or more sockets may be readable, depending on how many sockets you are waiting on.  You have to call `read()` on every socket that is readable, buffering the received data as needed, and then process the buffers before going back to `select()`.

Comment: This only considers reading. You need to consider writing as well.

Comment: @EJP You seem to be over-thinking the problem. This is a homework assignment, not the redesign of the Apache server.

Comment: @user3386109 It probably isn't what the assignment means, but if you want an actually non-blocking server, you *do* need to consider it! (Otherwise your server isn't always non-blocking)

Comment: @user3386109 Nonsense. I am addressing the question that was asked: 'is it possible?' In my opinion it is a poorly worded and impossible assignemnt, and it is disturbing that people are being marked on it, and apparently being educated withmisinformation.

Comment: @immibis True, but if you were making a production server, you wouldn't have restrictions against `fork` and `O_NONBLOCK`. The point of the exercise, if I understand it correctly, is simply to use `select` correctly to read from multiple sockets, without blocking in a `read`.

Comment: @EJP [Wittgenstein's ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children#Wittgenstein.27s_ladder)

Comment: There is an excellent reference : unix network programming the sockets api that explains all this.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not a Wittgenstein fan in the first place, having studied him in 1974, and I'm not also a fan of introducing pretentious and obscure terminology, or appeals to irrelevant authorities, into a simple discussion. The point here is that the task is impossible, and the question in my mind is whether the examiner knew it. If you have some *evidence* on the point, produce it. Merely posting links to external sites of zero relevance is ns not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.

1. `select()` blocks, and therefore so does any program that calls it.
2. The behaviour defined by Posix for `send()` in blocking mode is that it blocks until all the data supplied has been transferred to the socket send buffer. Unless you're going to delve into low-water marks and so on, it is impossible to know in advance whether there is enough room in he socket send buffer for any given `send()` to complete without blocking, and therefore impossible for any program that calls `send()` not to block.

   Note that `select()` doesn't help you with this. It can tell when you when there is *some* room, but not when there is *enough.*

Comment: "Blocking `select` calls" != "Blocking sockets". Upvote for the `send` caveat though (which also seems to apply to `write`)

Comment: @immibis The assignment as quoted says 'your *server* must not be blocking'. Poorly worded. The caveat applies to `send(), sendto(), sendmsg(), write(), ...`

Comment: Yes, poorly worded; however, it's fairly obvious they want you to block on `select`, but not obvious you're allowed to block on `send`/`write`.

Comment: @immibis I don't agree that it's 'fairly obvious' at all. It's much more likely that the examiner isn't aware of the Posix rule, and believes that a blocking `send()` will return a short count when it can't buffer all the data. Plenty of other people do.